# Remove labels with low counts from `scipy.ndimage.labels` result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using [`scipy.ndimage.labels`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) to label features in an array. To make the issue reproducible, this results in the following array, for example:

```
import numpy as np
labels = np.array([[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

I'm analyzing the results with `numpy.unique`:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))
```

Which prints:

```
{0: 6288, 1: 247, 2: 542, 3: 118, 4: 1811, 5: 454, 6: 247, 7: 293}
```

I'm only interested in features with counts of min 1000, so I'd like to change every number in `labels` to `0` if the feature isn't big enough. Also, the labels themselves have to change so there are no gaps going from `0` to `n`. So if I run `numpy.unique` on the modified `labels` array again:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))
```

I'd like to get:

```
{0: 8189, 1: 1811}
```

The idea:

```
i = 0
for u, c in zip(unique, counts):
    if c < 1000:
        labels = np.where(labels != u, labels, 0)
    else:
        labels = np.where(labels != u, labels, i)
        i += 1
```

What's a better way to solve this with `numpy` array methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With `unique[counts<1000]` get the *invalid* labels and then use `np.isin` to get a mask and finally assign those in `labels` as `0s` -

```
labels = np.asarray(labels)
labels[np.isin(labels,unique[counts<1000])] = 0
```

Then, relabel the valid ones to be in *sequence* with `np.unique` and its optional arg `return_inverse` set as `True` -

```
labels = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(labels.shape)
```

Then, running `np.unique` gives us -

```
In [122]: unique, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
     ...: print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))
{0: 8189, 1: 1811}
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you don't care about `labels` and simply want the expected output of valid unique labels and their counts, there's a more efficient way starting with the input `labels`, `unique` and `counts` -

```
mask_counts = counts<1000
unique[mask_counts] = 0
new_count = np.bincount(unique,counts).astype(int)
valid_mask = new_count!=0
valid_count = new_count[valid_mask]
valid_unqlbl = np.arange(len(valid_count))
out = dict(zip(valid_unqlbl,valid_count))
```

Sample output -

```
In [178]: out
Out[178]: {0: 8189, 1: 1811}
```

Comment: @finefoot Edited to use `.reshape(labels.shape)` to get new labels - `labels_new`. So, should be good now to preserve shape.

Comment: @finefoot Just change `labels_new = np...` to `labels = np..`?